# Handler Goblal Exceptions Spring - add data when sending exception

Tags: spring, exception

I have a doubt about how to pass more data to throw an exception, I want to pass more data at the time of launching it, to put that data in the service response ..
I have an exception handler class labeled @ControllerAdvice in spring, but I don't know the best way to pass the data.

This is the code I have

`throw new OcspException("Exception OCSP");`

```
public class OcspException extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public OcspException(String businessMessage) {
        super(businessMessage);
    }

    public OcspException(String businessMessage, Throwable throwable) {
        super(businessMessage, throwable);
    }

}
```

```
@ExceptionHandler(OcspException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> exception(OcspException exception,HttpServletRequest request) {

        ResponseException response = new ResponseException();
        response.setCode("404");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

    }
```

**I have the idea to do it, but I don't know if it is a good practice ... in the OcspException class to create attributes with their setter and getters, and create the constructor that receives this data, to then extract the data in exception controller**

```
throw new OcspException("Exception OCSP","Hello");
```

```
public class OcspException extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String m;

    public OcspException(String businessMessage) {
        super(businessMessage);
    }

    public OcspException(String businessMessage, Throwable throwable) {
        super(businessMessage, throwable);
    }

    public OcspException(String businessMessage, String message) {

        super(businessMessage);
        setM(message);

    }

    public String getM() {
        return m;
    }

    public void setM(String m) {
        this.m = m;
    }


}
```

```
@ExceptionHandler(OcspException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> exception(OcspException exception,HttpServletRequest request) {



        ResponseException response = new ResponseException();
        response.setCode("404");
        response.setDetails(exception.getM() );
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making an model called ErrorDetails which will hold a timestamp, message, and details.

It may look like this:

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ErrorDetails {
  private LocalDateTime timeStamp;
  private String message;
  private String details;
}
```

Here's a sample of what my custom exceptions usually look like:

```
@Data
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class OrderNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
  private final String message;

  public OrderNotFoundException(String message) {
      super(message);
      this.message = message;
  }
}
```

Then for the @ExceptionHandler:

```
@ExceptionHandler(OrderNotFoundException.class)
public ResponseEntity<ErrorDetails> 
orderNotFoundException(OrderNotFoundException ex, WebRequest request) {
      ErrorDetails errorDetails = ErrorDetails.builder()
              .timeStamp(LocalDateTime.now())
              .message(ex.getMessage())
              .details(request.getDescription(false))
              .build();

      return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

The error response for an order not found ends up being this:

```
{
  "timeStamp": "2019-10-07T21:31:37.186",
  "message": "Order with id 70 was not found.",
  "details": "uri=/api/v1/order"
}
```

This way you can add whatever extra details in the ErrorDetails object. I hope that helps!